# how to create an "all-others" url pattern in django?

Tags: django, django-urls

In my django site, I have four views:  index, foo, bar, and backstop.

If I'm asked for the / url, I want to use the index view

If I get a url like /foo/123, I want to use the foo view.

If I get a url like /bar/123, I want to use the bar view.

if I get *any other* url, I want to call the backstop view.  (so it could be /backstop, /baz/123, /some/other/path, /zipidee/doo/dah/)

I've tried a few variations on:

```
url ('/foo', 'myapp.views.foo'),
url ('/bar', 'myapp.views.bar'),
url ('/', 'myapp.views.index),
url ('.*', 'myapp.views.backstop')
```

But I either seem to end up getting the index for everything, or the backstop for everything.

Someone must have done this before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` match every url, because every url contains at least `/`.

Try following:

```
url ('foo', 'myapp.views.foo'),
url ('bar', 'myapp.views.bar'),
url ('^$', 'myapp.views.index'),
url ('', 'myapp.views.backstop')
```

Comment: You don't need the `/` before `foo` or `bar`, you ought to use `^foo` and `^bar` instead.